# Dynamic use of SqlBulkTools

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulktools

I'm trying to make a generic `sqlbulktools` method, so that it can take any model as input. Here is the main method:

```
public void InsertOrUpdateTableMatchOnString<T>(string tableName, List<T> models) where T : class, IModel
    {
        BulkOperations bulk = new BulkOperations();

        using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                bulk.Setup<T>()
                    .ForCollection(models)
                    .WithTable(tableName)
                    .AddAllColumns()
                    .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                    .SetIdentityColumn(x => x.Id)
                    .MatchTargetOn(x => x.AgreementId)
                    .MatchTargetOn(x => x.GetMatchOn())
                    .Commit(conn);
            }

            trans.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of a model which is used as an input:

```
public class Company : IModel
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BaseCurrency { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CINumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime SignUpDate { get; set; }
    public int AgreementId { get; set; }

    public PropertyInfo GetMatchOn()
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == "Name");
    }

    public Company SetProperties(CompanyData data, Customer customer)
    {
        Name = data.Name;
        BaseCurrency = data.BaseCurrencyHandle.Code;
        Address1 = data.Address1;
        PostalCode = data.PostalCode;
        City = data.City;
        Country = data.Country;
        TelephoneNumber = data.TelephoneNumber;
        Contact = data.Contact;
        WebSite = data.WebSite;
        Email = data.Email;
        CINumber = data.CINumber;
        SignUpDate = data.SignUpDate;
        AgreementId = customer.ecid;

        return this;
    }
}
```

And here is the interface the model implements:

```
public interface IModel
{
    long? Id { get; set; }
    int AgreementId { get; set; }
    PropertyInfo GetMatchOn();
}
```

The problem is that I can't use the `GetMatchOn()` method in the `.MatchTargetOn(x => x.GetMatchOn())` method call - it will only take a property like `.MatchTargetOn(x => x.AgreementId)`, otherwise I get an error. But I need it to be a method as it is not the same property from model to model, that I want to get matched. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: To do this effectively you need an overload of `MatchTargetOn` that takes a `PropertyInfo`, to allow for dynamic use. You may also want to consider an overload that just takes the property name as a `string` and effectively implement what `GetMatchOn` is doing now (incidentally, using `nameof` there is better than a hard-coded literal), since it saves a check that `PropertyInfo` really refers to a property of the class in question (and not some property of another class).

Comment: Note that optimizing dynamic property access (which you may need when you're copying lots and lots of rows), whether done through a name, a `PropertyInfo` or an `Expression`, is its own challenge; compiled delegates are simple but do not perform as well as a dynamic method that accesses all properties in a typed manner (although generating this method is much harder to get right).

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast :) Im sorry if I've misunderstood you, but it sounds like you think I can make an overload of MatchTargetOn myself, but SqlBulkTools is a package I'm using, so I cannot change that part of the code - does that mean it cannot be done?

Comment: It can still be done if there is no overload, but less conveniently. `MatchTargetOn` will accept either a `Func<T, TProp>` or an `Expression<Func<T, TProp>>` to specify the property; you can construct either of these dynamically, although it's not pretty at all, in fact, the code involved makes my head hurt a little. You could consider inverting responsibility and passing whatever the type of `.BulkInsertOrUpdate()` is to a method in `IModel`, so the type itself can call `.MatchTargetOn()`. Admittedly this will probably also allow it to call methods it's not supposed to, but it is easier.

Comment: Check [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions), I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Jeroen Mostert. What ended up working for me was adding a method to the models - fx like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Company, object>> GetMatchOn()
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Company));
            MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name");
            UnaryExpression convertedProperty = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
            Expression<Func<Company, object>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Company, object>>(convertedProperty, parameter);

            return lambda;
        }
```

and then calling it from the main method like this:

```
public void InsertOrUpdateTableMatchOnString<T>(string tableName, List<T> models) where T : class, IModel<T, object>
        {
            BulkOperations bulk = new BulkOperations();

            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConString))
                {
                    bulk.Setup<T>()
                        .ForCollection(models)
                        .WithTable(tableName)
                        .AddAllColumns()
                        .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                        .SetIdentityColumn(x => x.Id)
                        .MatchTargetOn(x => x.AgreementId)
                        .MatchTargetOn(models.First().GetMatchOn())
                        .Commit(conn);
                }

                trans.Complete();
            }
        }
```